# PhpMyAdmin Blank Page on fodora 22 localhost server

Tags: linux, fedora, lamp, phpmyadmin

I follow this guide to install LAMP server on fedora 22 workstation

[How To Install LAMP Stack (Apache, MariaDB And PHP) In Fedora 22](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-lamp-stack-apache-mariadb-and-php-in-fedora-22/)

Everything working well except phpmyadmin.

When i need access it of the browser i see nothing (blank page)

How i can fix this issue ?

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Check  `/var/log/httpd/error_log` for errors when you load the page - it might contain PHP error messages. Possibly also check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for any SELinux block messages when you load that page. If there's anything useful in the logs, please add it to your question.

Comment: thanks TessellatingHeckler for help , i see the result of erro_log as below
`[Thu May 28 22:19:57.174706 2015] [:error] [pid 10968] [client 192.168.1.10:35767] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function __() in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/core.lib.php on line 245
`

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243704/call-to-undefined-function-error-phpmyadmin and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537617/phpmyadmin-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function - looks like incorrect permissions to /etc/phpMyAdmin or the PHP session folder, or maybe a missing dependency (*ahem* and http://www.adminer.org/en/phpmyadmin/ ).

Comment: Awesome , it`s working , thnaks sir TessellatingHeckler for your help 
thank you again.

Comment: That's good. I've put my comments as a proper answer to the question - if you can, please mark it accepted, or add your own answer with exactly what you changed to make it work - otherwise this will show as an unanswered question forever. Thanks.

Comment: surly, but sorry i have no point enough to vote your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting my comments above into an answer:

Check `/var/log/httpd/error_log` for errors when you load the page - it might contain PHP error messages. Possibly also check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for any SELinux block messages when you load that page. If there's anything useful in the logs, please add it to your question.

-- update --

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243704/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537617/ - it looks like incorrect permissions to `/etc/phpMyAdmin` or the PHP session folder, or maybe a missing dependency.